# Graph Theory, Bipartition

Tags: graph-theory

I am proving the theorem that states:
Any simple graph $G$ is bipartite if and only if every cycle of $G$ has even length.

The forward direction is trivial. The backward direction, I believe is correct, but I need help on the last statement:

Suppose that all cycles of $G$ have even length. Pick $\quad$ $x \in V(G)$. Then we construct a bipartition $V(G)=V_{1}(G)\cup V_{2}(G)$ as follows.

Let $V_{1}(G)=\{x\}\cup N^{2}(x) \cup N^{4}(x) \cup \cdots =\bigcup_{k \quad\text{is even}}N^{k}(x)$

$V_{2}(G)=N^{1}(x)\cup N^{3}(x)\cup \cdots \cup=\bigcup_{k \quad \text{is odd}}N^{k}(x),$

where $N^{k}=\{d(v,u)=k\}$ is the $k^{th}$ neighborhood
We need only show that no edges are inside $V_{1}(G)$ or $V_{2}(x).$

Suppose towards a contradiction that there exists an edge $e$ in $V_{1}(G).$ Then we can find a cycle containing this $e$ with odd length, this is a contradiction to the assumption.
This completes the proof in this direction.
But my question is how can we find such a cycle containing this $e$ of odd length. Any hints or answers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $e = u_{2s}v_{2t}$, where $d(x, u_{2s}) = 2s$ and $d(x, v_{2t}) = 2t$ for some $s,t \in \mathbb Z$. Then for each $i \in \{1, \ldots, 2s - 1\}$ and for each $j \in \{1, \ldots, 2t - 1\}$, there exist $u_i, v_j \in V(G)$ such that $d(x, u_i) = i$ and $d(x, v_j) = j$. But then:
$$
x \to u_1 \to u_2 \to \cdots \to u_{2s-1} \to u_{2s} \to v_{2t} \to v_{2t-1} \to \cdots \to v_1 \to x
$$
is a cycle of length $2s + 1 + 2t$, which is odd.

Comment: @ Adriano, what about some intersections of edges. How do we account for those.

Comment: why must each set have at least two vertices.

Comment: But what if some $N^{i}$  only contains one vertex. Having an even cycle does not guarantee at least two vertices in one set.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v_1,v_2$ be the vertices of $e$. Then $d(x,v_1)=2k_1$ and $d(x,v_2)=2k_2$. Therefore $$x...\underbrace{v_1v_2}_{e} ... x$$ is a cycle and has length $2k_1+2k_2+1$.

Comment: Thank you @Tom. But the $k_{1}$ and the $k_{2}$ must be distinct. Also, how did you get the $2k_{1}+2k_{2}+1$ cycle.

Comment: @ReneCabrera That was just a typo. The vertex $v_1$ connects to $x$ through a path of length $2k_1$ and the vertex $v_2$ connects to $x$ thought a path of length $2k_2$. Then the cycle is formed by going from $x$ to $v_1$ using the $2k_1$ length path, then from $v_1$ to $v_2$ using $e$ and finally from $v_2$ to $x$ using the path of length $2k_2$.

Comment: Thank you for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality there is only one connected component. The claim is that every edge of $G$ connects a vertex in $V_1(G)$ to a vertetx in $V_2(G)$.
If not, then there are vertices $u$ and $v$ such that $d(x,u)$ and $d(x,v)$ have the same parity. Thus there is a cycle $x \to u \to v \to x$ of length $d(x,u)+1+d(x,w)$, which is odd. This is a contradiction.

Comment: what if two vertices are equal, then there is no cycle necessarily. Namely, if some $N^{i}$ only contains one vertex. Having an even cycle does not guarantee at least two vertices in one set.